# URL function with i18n localization

Tags: uri, i18n-l10n

I'm using the Rate module for voting. When an anonymous user clicks on the voting widget, the user is redirected to a url "user/login-to-rate". I'm also using i18n for localization. The issue with both of these together is that when I'm on a page with the URL "en/my-url" and I click on the voting widget, I'm redirected to "de/user/login-to-rate" where "de" is my default language. Ideally the user should be going to "en/user/login-to-rate" i.e. user selected language should be respected.

Going into details, I find that the rate module calls `url()` using the following code:

```
print url('user/login-to-rate', array('query' => $query, 'absolute' => TRUE));
```

There is no language paramater that is passed, which means the default site language gets selected.

Am I missing something here in the configuration? Has anyone faced a similar problem and can help?

Answer (score 3):

url() uses the current language by default, you only need to pass the language to it if you want another language, e.g. when sending mails to a user with a different language.

If you're on en/something and the global language is not en, then something else might be problem, for example incorrectly configured language recognication.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing it the language object then. Without looking at the module, something like:

```
global $language;
print url('user/login-to-rate', array('query' => $query, 'absolute' => TRUE, 'language'=>$language));
```

If this works, make sure you submit it as a patch to the module.